# Excel formula (preferable) or python script to check for unique numbers in large file

Tags: excel

I am trying to check for a unique minimum number in column F - it should not be the same as the rows previous. File has over one thousand rows.

[image]

Comment: Should be doable with `MINIFS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365:

Put this in F2 and copy down the dataset.

```
=MIN(FILTER(A2:E2,ISERROR(MATCH(A2:E2,$F$1:F1,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks Scott - as a follow on how would i do this with text?                                         eg R1 John James Martin Andrew Mary - Output = John                                                               
     R2 John James Martin Andrew Mary - Output = James because john is already the OP above

Comment: That is a new question.  This answers the question here.  Please consider marking this as correct and posting a new question about using text.